# t-sql 2012 parse out messages to think period or no period is same value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

In a SQL Server 2012 database, I am supposed to count the number of times each 'canned' message is used for elementary students in the last school year and the current school  year.

The following is the T-SQL that I currently am using:

```
Declare @Delimiter char(2) = '. ';

;WITH GetTheComments(Comments) AS
(
    SELECT 
        GS.Comments
    FROM 
        dbo.Enrol Enrol
    JOIN 
        dbo.Student Student ON Student.StudentID = Enrol.StudentID
    JOIN 
        dbo.GS GS ON GS.StudentID = Student.Studentid
                  AND (GS.Comments IS NOT NULL)
                  AND (GS.Comments <> '')
    WHERE
        Enrol.grade IN ('KG', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06')
        AND Enrol.endYear BETWEEN 2016 AND 2017
), Pieces (Comments, start, stop) AS 
(
    SELECT 
        Comments, 
        CAST(1 AS BIGINT) AS start, 
        CAST(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, Comments) AS BIGINT) AS stop 
    FROM 
        GetTheComments

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        Comments, 
        CAST(stop + Len(@Delimiter) AS BIGINT) AS start, 
        CAST(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, Comments, stop + Len(@Delimiter)) AS BIGINT) AS stop 
    FROM 
        Pieces
    WHERE 
        stop > 0
),
EachComment(Comments) AS
(
     SELECT 
         LTrim(SUBSTRING(Comments, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE LEN(Comments) END)) AS Comments 
     FROM Pieces
)
SELECT 
    Comments, Count(*) AS Counts
FROM
    EachComment
WHERE
    Comments <> ''
GROUP BY 
    Comments
ORDER BY 
    Counts DESC, Comments ASC;
```

An example of multiple messages in the one GS.Comments field would look like the following:

This student is good at math. This student turns in their assignments on time. This student seems to enjoy school.

An example of when one messages is in  the one GS.Comments field would look like the following:

This student seems to enjoy school

The problem is the `GS.Comments` column is defined as `varchar(1200)`. There can be one message in the column, and/or there can be lots of messages in this column. Each message ends with a period and there is a space between each message that has more than 1 message in the `varchar(1200)` column.

When there is only 1 message, there is no period after the message.

The problem is there can be results that look like the following

```
message                                        count
-----------------------------------------------------
This student seems to enjoy school.             150
This student seems to enjoy school               25
```

Basically there is a count for a message with a period and there is a count for when there is not a period for the same message.

Thus can you show me what I can do with the sql listed above so the messages are treated as being the same. Basically I want 1 message with 1 count for what I listed above.

Comment: You seriously need to set-up some sample data covering all the test cases you mention (best if it comes from you instead of us guessing our way through it.)

Answer (score 0):

If the question is only about the trailing full stop, then perhaps using a case expression like the following would assist:

```
SELECT
      case when Comments like '%.' then Comments else (Comments + '.') end as Comments
    , COUNT(*) AS Counts
FROM EachComment
WHERE Comments <> ''
GROUP BY
      case when Comments like '%.' then Comments else (Comments + '.') end
ORDER BY Counts DESC, Comments ASC;
```